# Adjusting position of Multiple UILabels

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a screen that has multiple `UILabel`. The labels are set to `[myLabel sizeToFit];` along with `myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;`. This causes all the labels below this multiline label to overlap. Is there a smarter way to auto adjust the positions of all `UILabel` below this multiline labels so they do not overlap and adjust accordingly. I cannot use layoutSubviews as our app still has to support 4.3.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No it won't auto adjust. You'll have to do it with help of code.
2. As the size of your `UILabel` is decided dynamically. You'll have to adjust the position of the `UILabel` which follows accordingly.
3. **Alternate solution to your problem is, you can use the `UITableView`.**
4. So even if your text increases. Rest of the `UILabels` which will be
   in another cell will be placed properly.
5. As you can easily set the property to `cell.textLabel` it won't be much effort to create a `UITableView`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yep I ended creating a UItableview.